# How can I pass an argument to a sub-page in an Appcelerator TabGroup?

Tags: tabs, arguments, parameter-passing, appcelerator

I am making a tab based app with Appcelerator. On the master page (info.js) there is a listview showing a list of titles and ids. If one clicks on the item, the id should be passed to the details page (info_details.js). **How can I pass the id from the master to the details page in a tabgroup?**

I am using code from the sample app, but it does not pass any argument to the sub (details) page:
https://github.com/appcelerator-developer-relations/appc-sample-ti520/blob/master/app/controllers/index.js

```
function onListViewItemclick(e) {
 var item = e.section.getItemAt(e.itemIndex);
 //var controllerName = e.itemId;
 openSample("info_details");
}

function openSample(controllerName) {
var controller = Alloy.createController(controllerName);
$.info.open(controller.getView());
}
```

Index.xml:

```
<TabGroup>
    <Tab title="Tab 1" icon="KS_nav_ui.png" id="main">
        <Window title="Nominate">
            <Label>I am Window 1</Label>
        </Window>
    </Tab>
    <Tab title="Tab 2" icon="KS_nav_views.png" id="info">
        <Window title="Info">
            <Require src="info"/>
        </Window>
    </Tab>
</TabGroup>
```

The subpage (info_details) expects

```
var args = $.args;
var currentNid = args.nid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arguments via the [createController](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Alloy-method-createController) args parameter. In your case, you can do something like:

```
function onListViewItemclick(e) {

  //e.itemId or whatever you want to send to the controller
  openSample("info_details", {nid: e.itemId});
}

function openSample(controllerName, args) {
  //pass the args to createController
  var controller = Alloy.createController(controllerName, args);
  $.info.open(controller.getView());
```

}

Then in the `info_details`:

```
var args = $.args;
var currentNid = args.nid;
```